# Does Travis CI support Hack?

Tags: travis-ci, hacklang

I've written code completely in Hack, and I would like to use Travis CI to test my builds on various HHVM versions with Hack enabled. Does Travis CI support Hack when I select HHVM as the testing platform or is it just PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It provides both `hhvm`, which can run Hack, and `hh_client` which checks it.

However, Travis is running Ubuntu 12.04. This means you can only get HHVM 3.6 and will be unable to use any of the more recent features in both HHVM and Hack.

Comment: Does 3.6 have the bug that prevents PHPUnit from running due to the signature issue reported on GitHub or was that introduced in a later version?

Comment: 3.6 has that bug, so you'll either need to use a version of PHPUnit before 4.7, or a beta version.

Comment: I just want to post an update to state that Travis CI uses HHVM 3.5.0 currently, and to run a Hack project, you just need to specify the PHP language and that it should test the code only on hhvm. See [my .travis.yml](https://github.com/cozylife/hackfastalgos/blob/master/.travis.yml) for an example.